# convert XML attribute to json

Tags: json, sql-server, xml

As a simplified example, consider this table with two fields. One is a string and the other is XML.

```
SELECT TOP (1) [Source]
      , OrderParameter
  FROM [Rops].[dbo].[PreOrder]
```

- Source="MediaConversions"
- OrderParameter="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>"

Now I want to query the table and have the results as json, but also have the XML converted as json in one go.

```
SELECT TOP (1) [Source]
      , OrderParameter
  FROM [Rops].[dbo].[PreOrder]
for json path;
```

results in

> [{"Source":"MediaConversions","OrderParameter":"<ParameterList
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />"}]

But I want it to be converted into:

> [{"Source":"MediaConversions","OrderParameter":{ "ParameterList": [
> "x": 1, "y": 10] }
> ]

How to add "for json" to have the xml converted?

```
SELECT TOP (1) [Source]
      , select OrderParameter for json path????
  FROM [Rops].[dbo].[PreOrder]
for json path;
```

Comment: I don't understand why your "results in" can contain `<ParameterList ...` etc., when the entered data for `OrderParameter` is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`. I created a temp table in MS SQL Server and ran your second query (the one that ends in `for json path`), which gave me `[{"Source":"MediaConversions","OrderParameter":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>"}]`. I'm not sure I see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to pull out the inner text of the `ParameterList` node inside the XML. You can use `.value` and XQuery for this:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) [Source]
      , OrderParameter = (
           SELECT
              x = x.PL.value('(x/text())[1]','int'),
              y = x.PL.value('(y/text())[1]','int')
           FROM (VALUES( CAST(OrderParameter AS xml) )) v(OrderParameter)
           CROSS APPLY v.OrderParameter.nodes('ParameterList') x(PL)
           FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('ParameterList')
        )
  FROM [Rops].[dbo].[PreOrder]
FOR JSON PATH;
```

Comment: looks good, but orderparameter is ntext type and doing a cast(orderparam as xml).nodes is not valid

Comment: OK you can just place that in a `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`. Note that `ntext` is deprecated, and in any case you should store XML in an `xml` column

Comment: it's a 15 year old table which im trying to remove by putting it in mongodb so rather not change the schema. but thanks! learned a lot